# Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 to do a find/replace with next number in a sequence?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, sequence, replace

First let me say I am college student learning programing so please explain your answer as simply as possible (I’m not real familiar with regular expressions).
What I am trying to do is find some group of text and replace it with the same text but a number appended to the end and continue in this sequence until all of the text matching my search has been replaced.
For example say I have the text “foo*” appearing 100 times in my code. What I want to be able to do is replace “foo*” with “foo1”,”foo2”, “foo3”,….. ,”foo100”

Thanks

Comment: This cannot be done using just the Find/Replace dialog and Regex alone as it would have no idea which number to increment. You would have to write a small program or script to do so.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I thought about writing a small program, but thought I would see if I could save myself some work. I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with regular expressions and String's `Replace` method.

But `Regex` **doesn't have any keyword to continue the sequence**.You have to do it yourself!

```
Regex r=new Regex("foo");
r.Replace("foo hey hello",get100s("foo"));

public string get100s(string inp)
{
string s="";
for(int i=1;i<100;i++)s+=(inp+i);
return s;
}
```

Instead you can use the Strings's `Replace` method to the same thing..

```
s.Replace("foo",get100s("foo"));
```